# How should I flag an offensive username?

Tags: support, flags, display-names, offensive

I just saw someone whose username is [dot-net-Slut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529995/dot-net-slut).

As a non-native speaker, I don't know if it's really offensive, but how could I flag an offensive username or "About Me" content?

Comment: dunno, I think that's hot.  brb, <strike>abusing my mod privileges to get a date.</strike> AW HELL NO!

Comment: BTW--To my mind this particular case only rises to the level of *"not very professional"*, and does not call for any action.

Comment: @Won't If you thought for a minute that _wasn't_ a dude, then you are required to sign out of the Internet for a period of 30 days and return your mouse and keyboard to Tim Berners-Lee (temporary safe keeping).

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. It's asking about offensive user *names*, not abusive users. Reopened.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can flag one of their posts as "in need of moderator attention" and describe it in the textarea there. It doesn't necessarily have to concern the post being flagged.

[image: dialog box]

Comment: wow that was quick :P nicely done.

Comment: I am confused by the diagram. Please post more clearly.